# firewalking output rules

Tags: firewalls

Scenario is as follows:

In a vulnhub lab, I got limited shell. By means of

`attacker> nc -lvp 1234`

`victim> nc _attacker_ip 1234`

I found out that ubuntu's ufw is limiting outgoing traffic.

Since I'm no root, I can't list ufw rules. Is there any software that can detect outgoing rules? I guess it wouldn't be that hard to set a server on the attacker machine to listen in ALL ports, and a client in the victim machine that would "tcp-ping" every port, so it can detect outgoing rules.

Is there any similar software out there? If not, I would maybe roll my own.

Comment: Are you allowed to run commands like `netstat -antup` (add the `c` option for continuous output) ? That would show current activity, although there must lots of RELATED traffic that is allowed thru, being initiated by the Ubuntu machine. I am not familiar with UFW but the documentation says it is basically a front-end for iptables, then maybe you could query iptables like this: `iptables -nL`.

Answer (score 1):

A generic way to test available outbound ports, independent of the location of the port filter (e.g. local host-based firewall, perimeter firewall), is exactly what you proposed - trying to connect to an external system, that is listening on all available ports.

You do not have to re-invent a mechanism for the target system of the connection attempts, because such a system is readily available: [PortQuiz](http://portquiz.net/)

If you do already have limited shell access, you can write a short bash-script (or whatever scripting language you have available), that tries to connect to PortQuiz and outputs all successful attempts.

You can also try more complex approaches like [DNS tunneling](https://medium.com/@galolbardes/learn-how-easy-is-to-bypass-firewalls-using-dns-tunneling-and-also-how-to-block-it-3ed652f4a000) to setup your communication channel, but I wouldn't consider this in scope of your question.